# Create a URL that redirects to either App Store, Play Store or Website depending on user agent

Tags: url, redirect, web

What is the easiest way to create 1 link that will re-direct to either the App Store, Google Play Store, or a website, depending on the user agent?

- iOS device should redirect to App Store.
- Android device should redirect to Google Play.
- Any other device should redirect to website.

Answer (score 2):

Use PHP

```
<?php
$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry == true) 
{ 
header('Location: http://mobile.site.com/');
//OR
echo "<script>window.location='http://mobile.site.com'</script>";
}
?>
```